# Pycharm powershell shortcut

Tags: python, powershell, pycharm

I recently started using PyCharm with Powershell as terminal shell, however I am experiencing problems with keyboard shortcuts. While terminal screen is active, 'ctrl+c' should interrupt current command, but it is not. Also 'ctrl+end' should clear current line, however this shortcut also is not working.

Is there any way to make PyCharm's terminal properly react to PowerShell's keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard interrupt in debug mode PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913490/keyboard-interrupt-in-debug-mode-pycharm)