# Catching exception of PyCharms "Stop process"

Tags: python, pycharm

In my Python script, I operate an infinite loop. I want to make sure that if I stop it, all the changes I made are reversed.

Currently, I execute the script directly from the terminal, and I stop the script via STRG+C.

```
a = 0

try:
    while True:
        a = 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    a = 0
```

However, I want to execute the script in PyCharm. There, I can't use STRG+C, but the "Stop" button, which will result in PyCharm returning `Process finished with exit code -1`. How can I catch this exception?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913490/keyboard-interrupt-in-debug-mode-pycharm